# How To Increase heap space in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a project in which i want to implement around 6000 else if statements , but the problem is when i paste the code in my java file, i get two errors , and the text cannot be pasted in the java file.i was thinking if there is a way to store else if statements in Strings.xml like strings are saved  or can the code be split into two class files?

here are some screenshots of the errors i get 
error 1 http://pho.to/4I2Zh

error 2 http://pho.to/4I2c8

Comment: _What exactly does the error say_? What does it come from?

Comment: seems like compile time error, there is a limit of method body ... 6000 ifs ... bad idea ... could you tell us what for? or post example if  ... else if ... maybe Dictionary/HashMap could help with this

Comment: @selvin check the images please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The large heap will be the same as normal heap until your app needs more memory for a task. Put this line in the application tag. However this works above api level 15 :-

```
android:largeHeap= true
```

For Eclipse, edit the eclipse.ini file and add these lines :-

-Xms40m

-Xmx512m

If these lines are alraedy present, just change the values

Comment: @RahulGupta question is: How To Increase heap space in **eclipse** not in android app

Comment: @Selvin - I have modified my answer. I have not posted the location of eclipse.ini file. I hope i don't get downvoted for that.;)

Comment: after doing this when i launch eclipse i get "Failed to create Virtual Machine"

Comment: Try these values. check your eclipse.ini file. There may be some error in it